# XMLHttpRequest.open with username/password parameters Not Working

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Basically this request never goes through. Nothing shows up on the console and the status is still 0 instead of a valid status code.

```
xhr.open("GET", uri, true, username, password);
```

Whereas setting a header does work.

```
xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: I had to check the specs because I never used that optional arguments in the `send` method. Apparently you have to set the [`withCredentials`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-withcredentials-attribute) flag when performing a cross-origin request. ( [`MDN - withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) )

Comment: In which browsers?